# Apache 403 on multiple domains pointing to the same web root

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403

I'm running serverpilot on linode, which installs Ubuntu 14.4.

I need to point three domains to the same modx install. The first domain that modx was setup with works fine. When I added  the second domain to the vhosts that worked also worked.

When I try to point the second domain to a new virtual context within modx I get a 503 error?

Some posts suggest that Require all granted needs to be added, however, my main.conf file seems to have that in place:

```
<Directory ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteRule . -
</Directory>
```

Could this be a server user permissions issue? I unzipped a file with root and then reset ownership back to the username and group with chown..

Any tests that i can make to find out where the error is?

Advice most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

On servers managed by ServerPilot, you can look in the following log file on your server for an app's apache errors:

```
/var/log/serverpilot/log/APPNAME/APPNAME_apache.error.log
```

That should provide some more info on actual error that's happening.

Also, it's possible that the modx documentation is out of date, but the following doc claims that only up to apache 2.2 is supported:

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/getting-started/server-requirements

ServerPilot installs and configures apache 2.4 on your server, not apache 2.2.